# В чем проблема при установке Alcatraz?

Tags: xcode, swift, swift3

Судя по официальному сайту все должно быть настолько просто, что даже не знаю... Выполняем эту команду в терминале и запускаем Xocde

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/deploy/Scripts/install.sh | sh
```

И ничего не изменилось... У меня нет того, что продемонстрировано на этом скриншоте: [смотреть скриншот](http://alcatraz.io/images/menu@2x.png)

Comment: если  у тебя Xcode 8,  то у них на GitHub'e написано:     - Please note that plugins are not supported by Xcode 8. See #475 for more information

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов прочитал. Как я понял, в Xcode 8 больше нет поддержки плагинов? И как теперь быть? Конкретно с Realm - там есть парочка плагинов необходимых плагинов...

Comment: Ну, искать способы как прикрутить Realm без Alcatraz.

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов прикольно. Спасибо.

Comment: @ИсмаилХасбулатов перенесите свой комментарий в ответ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если у тебя Xcode 8, то у них на GitHub'e написано:

> Please note that plugins are not supported by Xcode 8. See #475 for
>   more information